# Tensorflow constant layer during trainig

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a small neural network, which is created with tf.layers:

```
# The neural network 
input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,5,5,1), name="input")
conv_layer_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(input, 3,        (1,1), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="conv_1")
conv_layer_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv_layer_1, 3, (1,1), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="conv_2")
conv_layer_3 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv_layer_2, 1, (1,1), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="conv_3")


# Trainingsstuff
prediction = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.float32, shape = (None, 5,5,1))
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(conv_layer_3, prediction)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)
```

This network I would like to train. After a few steps I need **conv_layer_2** to be constant. Is there a way to set conv_layer_2 to set to be constant?

---

Edit: The question wasn't accurate enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update*

So what you need is to train all the variables for some time and then have one of the layers to be fixed. Unfortunately, there is no straightforward to do that, because when you define an optimization operation, it is intrinsically associated to the variables it updates. But you can do something the following:

```
# The neural network 
input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,5,5,1), name="input")
conv_layer_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(input, 3,        (1,1), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="conv_1")
conv_layer_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv_layer_1, 3, (1,1), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="conv_2")
conv_layer_3 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv_layer_2, 1, (1,1), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="conv_3")

# Training stuff
prediction = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.float32, shape = (None, 5,5,1))
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(conv_layer_3, prediction)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
train_step_all = optimizer.minimize(loss)
# Now you remove the weights of conv_layer_2 from the trainable variables
trainable_vars = tf.get_collection_ref(GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
for var in conv_layer_2.variables:
    try:
        trainable_vars.remove(var)
    except ValueError: pass
# This op will train only the remaining layers
train_step_some = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Then you would need to design your logic to use `train_step_all` or `train_step_some` as needed. An alternative is to pass a `var_list` parameter to the `minimize` method with all the variables that you want updated in each case (you can also use a custom graph collection to save them as you construct the graph).

---

*Old answer (for reference)*

If you look at [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d), you will see there is a `trainable` parameter that you can set to `False` to prevent the layer weights from being updated during training (more specifically, the associated variables will not be added to the standard set of trainable variables used by optimizers by default). Note that these will then have the value given on initialization unless some specific value is loaded manually or from a checkpoint.

Comment: I need the layer to be variable and constant. This flag looks like only constant or variable. __trainable: Boolean, if True also add variables to the graph collection GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES (see tf.Variable).__

Comment: @SebastianH Yes, see my edited answer. That graph collection is the one used by optimizers to select the variables they need to optimize (unless otherwise stated).

Comment: @SebastianH In fact an alternative (and surely less practical) approach would be to somehow manually pick all the variables that you _don't_ want to be fixed and pass it to the [`minimize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#minimize) method of your optimizer.

Comment: @SebastianH I think I got what you meant now, check the updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for :)